# Run program with BrowserConfig?

Tags: java

im trying to create the following architecture:

1. User runs a packed jar
2. UI will open with simple control buttons like "Stop", "Open Config"
3. Open Config will open the browser, where the configurations for the program can be done

I've looked into vaadin and other frameworks, but it seems as if I need to setup a webserver etc for that. My solution needs to be very lightweight, and shouldn't rely on any software except base java. So to say a newbie could just run the jar, and do his configs via browser, or maybe even run it on a headless server and open the port to remotely change the settings.

Is that possible with java?

Comment: `shouldn't rely on any software except base java` then why do you want to use a browser for the config?

Comment: bc then i had a gui to configure the settings, even if the program is running headless

Comment: Your problem is till unclear, do you consider a webserver as an external software ? Because it will just be bundled in your jar, it will be quite simple